# How to calculate (N,*, input) matrix class (output, input) matrix(the result is (N,*,output)) by pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to rewrite what nn.Linear do. The question is that the input size is (N, *,in_feature) and weight size is (out_feature, in_feature). If I want the result to be (N,*,out_feature) using python, how should I wirte the code?

```
input @ weight.T
```

is not right, sadly.

Comment: Oh, matmul, I got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sizes need to match in order to apply `@`, *i.e.* `__matmul__`: the input `x` is shaped `(N, *, in_feature)` and the weight tensor `w` is shaped `(out_feature, in_feature)`.

```
x = torch.rand(2, 4, 4, 10)
w = torch.rand(5, 10)
```

Taking the transpose of `w` will get you a shape of `(in_feature, out_feature)`. Applying `__matmul__` between `x` and `w.T` will reduce down to a shape of `(N, *, out_feature)`:

```
>>> z = x@w.T
>>> z.shape
torch.Size([2, 4, 4, 5])
```

Or equivalently using [`torch.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html):

```
>>> z = torch.matmul(x, w.T)
```